# How to Plot 3-dimensional point to 2-dimensions?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose my data is

```
{{0., 0., 0.}, {-0.0203939, 0.0196729, 5.90962*10^-21}, {-0.0415497, 
  0.0386641, -2.9556*10^-19}, {-0.063427, 
  0.056934, -7.2506*10^-19}, {-0.0859824, 
  0.0744451, -6.65512*10^-19}, {-0.109169, 
  0.0911626, -3.87827*10^-19}, {-0.13294, 
  0.107054, -5.32617*10^-19}, {-0.157241, 0.12209, 
  3.83763*10^-19}, {-0.18202, 0.136244, 1.17879*10^-19}, {-0.207219, 
  0.149492, 9.4574*10^-19}, {-0.232781, 0.161815, 3.64846*10^-19}}
```

How can I take first and second element in every row, my expect data is `{{0,0},{-0.0203939, 0.0196729}...`? I have try `[[]]` but fails.

Any comments very be much appreciate!

Comment: 'Take[Data, 1, 2]' can get `{{0,0}}`, it seems close to the answer?

Comment: try `Most/@data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Take[data, All, 2]` works.

I have find the answer! `Take` is very useful!

Comment: by the way, can I use `[[]]` do same thing?

Comment: `data[[All, {1, 2}]]`